# Find largest accumulation of specific location lat long in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, geolocation

I have a table with locations and their matching address:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `locations` (
 `location_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `location_type` text  NOT NULL,
 `location_type_closer` text  NOT NULL,
 `location_tags` text NOT NULL,
 `location_name` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
 `matching_address` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `description` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
 `impressum` varchar(1500) NOT NULL,
 `visits` int(255) NOT NULL,
 `rating` int(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`location_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `addresses` (
 `address_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `continent` text NOT NULL,
 `country` text NOT NULL,
 `country_short` text NOT NULL,
 `state` text NOT NULL,
 `state_short` text NOT NULL,
 `state_closer` text NOT NULL,
 `postal_code` text NOT NULL,
 `town` text NOT NULL,
 `town_short` text NOT NULL,
 `street` text NOT NULL,
 `street_number` text NOT NULL,
 `lat` text NOT NULL,
 `lon` text NOT NULL,
 `rating` int(255) NOT NULL,
 `type` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`address_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=15 ;
```

My goal is to find an address with `type=town`, where most locations are having a specific type, for example restaurant. The matching address from the location are `type=street` or `type=street_number` and not `type=town`, so I think the only possible solution is over lat/long comparisation, but I have no idea how to implement that in SQL-querys, especially the JOIN of the tables. How can I do this?